# Фиксированный блок сверху

Tags: css

Приветствую всех.

Есть блок, который должен находиться наверху страницы, ширина его должна быть 100%.

Однако, по неизвестной мне причине, он съезжает на 15-20 пикселей вниз и на 15-15 пикселей влево.

[image]

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #1e64cc;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Если он фиксированный, добавьте top: 0; left: 0;

Comment: @dekameron, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите за правило переопределять стандартные стили. Первыми строками вашего файла .css должны быть

```
 * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: @dimka3210, большое спасибо, учту!